# два div'a в строку и встроенный iframe, который ломает отступы соседнего блока

Tags: css, вёрстка, iframe, html

Вот создала я два блока `div`, завернула их в обёртку и поставила в одну строку через атрибут `display: table-cell`. Всё хорошо, выровнялось как надо, если внутри блоков размещать текст: http://jsbin.com/sorenow/5/edit?html,css,output

Но мне нужно во втором блоке разместить `iframe`, и вот тут начинается веселье... Отступы какие-то повылазили:
http://jsbin.com/yamaqij/3/edit?html,css,output

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хоть в какую сторону копать-то, чтобы от этого избавиться? Плеер прекрасно умещается в блоке.. Почему в соседнем отступ сверху появился?

Comment: Прошу прощения, я ввел вас в заблуждение. Забудьте все, что я писал ранее - я обновил ответ.

Comment: @terron Теперь наконец всё ясно стало! Лучи добра вам)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решить вашу проблему можно двумя способами:

1. Добавьте левой колонке `vertical-align: top`.
2. Используйте сетки, построенные на float'ах (в таком случае вам также потребуется clearfix) или flex'е. Я бы порекомендовал именно это решение.

А почему текст съехал вниз? Посмотрите на скриншот и на красную линию:

[image: Скриншот]

Текст выравнивается по уровню строки самого большого элемента в строке таблицы.